# How to add plugins to Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I found this really cool [plugin](https://github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap) for Bootstrap that measures password strength. It looks good, and I want to use it, but I can't figure out how to make it work. According to the Github page, all you have to do to use it is "Just invoke the plugin on the password fields you want to attach a strength meter to.". Unfortunately, they don't tell you where to put the files, nor which javascript files you actually need to use.

I've been Googling every possible iteration of ways to add or install plugins for Bootstrap, and have come up empty each time. Does anyone have an answer here?

Comment: Requirements:jQuery 1.7 or higher **AND** Bootstrap 2 or 3. Did you add this libraries to your project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess the github pages can be confusing with all those source files. All you need to do is get the latest minified file from this page:

https://github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap/tree/master/dist

Download it, upload it, and load it into your HTML somewhere after your original bootstrap javascript file using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file/location/pwstrength-bootstrap-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

When you've done that, add the following javascript code to invoke the plugin on a class or element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':password').pwstrength();
});
```

Comment: That did it! I mean, really, would it have been so hard to include a line like that in the description? I figured there must be a javascript file you need to include, but it didn't say which one, so I thought that somehow Bootstrap had some kind of mechanism to find plugin files automatically. (Hey, what do I know? I do mostly back-end stuff anyway!) Anyway, thanks a million!

Comment: I guess it can sometimes be tricky for a programmer to place himself in the mindset of someone with less knowledge than himself. So obvious things like this while writing a manual or instruction are one of the first things you can forget =)

Comment: In hindsight, it was kind of a dumb oversight, but I just wasn't sure exactly which file needed to be included. And given the name of the only .js file in the main directory of the repository--and all the other .json files and whatnot--I thought there was some kind of trick to using Bootstrap plugins or something. Still, it's nice to read a response that is actually helpful instead of belittling.

Answer (score 1):

Just include the plugin css and javascripts after defining bootstrap in head of your html page.

something like this:

```
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="your plugin source"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to previous solutions: also **make sure to include jquery** in your html because it's required by bootstrap's js.