# How to run Bootstrap validator plugin

Tags: bootstrapping

I found interesting bootstrap plugin that i want to use. I downloaded it from https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator. However i dont'know how to make it work. I tried to use the same approach as mentioned here [How to add plugins to Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795104/how-to-add-plugins-to-bootstrap) but without success.

I tried to google some other way but came up empty. Could you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is in the official documentation buddy :
http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

> Form validation can be enabled in markup via the data-api or via JavaScript. Automatically enable form validation by adding data-toggle="validator" to your form element.